# Mongo DB and CodeIgniters

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, mongodb, gridfs

i want to build a system for storing documents (mostly words), it's a good idea to use MongoDB with GridFS?

i was planing to use mysql for the users and relations among the documents and only use mongo for files..

Comment: Why use a database at all for files?

Comment: Store the files securely!

Comment: A database doesn't mean the files are stored securely, proper encryption and passwords and isolation etc etc means it is

Comment: so it' better to store on directly on the FS with the proper permisions and stay away of GridFS or BLOB fields?

Comment: Well it is subjective as to which but your reasoning for storing it in MongoDB is weak, I would definitely stay away from blob storage but some people have had success with MongoDB storage but I don't think your scenairo merits use of a database for this

Comment: It was primary for research... but i Will follow your advice... Thanks1